# Duplicating files and renaming them based on a CSV using python

Tags: python, copy, rename

I have about 400 files that I need to duplicate and rename based on a csv file some of these files will be duplicated multiple times and given diffrent names.

I have CSV File and in column A its has the original name and in column B it has the new name.

IE
1000.jpg  1000 - 10x10.jpg
1000.jpg  1000 - 12x12.jpg

The python script I have thrown together will duplicate the file, rename it and move but only once. so if I need 4 copies of 1000.jpg renamed I only get one.

I am still super new to this so any help is much appreciated.

```
import os
import csv
import shutil
# open and store the csv file
IDs = {}
with open('old-names-new-names.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    timeReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    # build dictionary with associated IDs
    for row in timeReader:
        IDs[row[0]] = row[1]
# move files
path = '/start_location/'
tmpPath = '/save_location/'
for oldname in os.listdir(path):
    # ignore files in path which aren't in the csv file
    if oldname in IDs:
        try:
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(path, oldname), os.path.join(tmpPath, IDs[oldname]))
        except:
            print 'File ' + oldname + ' could not be renamed to ' + IDs[oldname] + '!'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're new to Python, I'd recommend using Pandas for this problem.

Here is how I would set it up.

Say you have your `csv` file with the `old_name` and `new_name` columns.

```
import pandas as pd 
name_map = pd.read_csv('old-names-new-names.csv')
name_map.head()

    new_name    old_name
0   new_33.txt  old_1.txt
1   new_18.txt  old_2.txt
2   new_29.txt  old_3.txt
3   new_31.txt  old_4.txt
4   new_64.txt  old_1.txt
```

In the `start_location` we have the following files:

```
import os 
os.listdir('start_location')
['old_1.txt', 'old_4.txt', 'old_2.txt', 'old_3.txt']
```

Our `save_location` directory is empty.

To copy the files over, we can do a quick loop over the Pandas dataframe like this, using `shutil` to copy the files to the new directory with the name from the `new_name` column.

```
import shutil 
for i, r in name_map.iterrows():
    shutil.copy('start_location/{}'.format(r.old_name), 'save_location/{}'.format(r.new_name))
```

When we inspect our destination directory, we see everything is there:

```
os.listdir('save_location')

['new_60.txt',
 'new_29.txt',
 'new_31.txt',
 'new_64.txt',
 'new_48.txt',
 'new_33.txt',
 'new_96.txt',
 'new_18.txt']
```

If you do not want to use pandas, consider this option:

```
import os
import csv
import shutil
with open('old-names-new-names.csv','rt') as csvfile:
    timeReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    i = 0 
    for row in timeReader:
        if i > 0:
            start_loc = row[1]
            save_loc = row[0]
            shutil.copy('start_location/{}'.format(start_loc), 'save_location/{}'.format(save_loc))
        i+=1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but i am having issues getting Pandas to install on my mac is there a method you could suggest that does not include installing it.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You're only getting one copy because you are using a dictionary, which use unique keys. Therefore, each time you try to save a new ID with

> IDs[row[0]] = row[1]

It will overwrite the previous one if that dictionary key is the same. For example: *1000.jpg*

Instead I recommend using a list of tuples and just appending the list as you go

```
>>> with open('old-names-new-names.csv') as csvfile:
...     timeReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
...     for row in timeReader:
...             IDs.append((row[0], row[1]))
... 
>>> IDs
[('1000.jpg', '1000-10x10.jpg'), ('1000.jpg', '1000-12x12.jpg'), ('1000.jpg', '1000-15x15.jpg')]
```

Then you could iterate through IDs to do your renaming logic and use indexes on the tuples:

```
>>> for ID in IDs:
...     print('old name:' + ID[0] + ' new name:' + ID[1])
... 
old name:1000.jpg new name:1000-10x10.jpg
old name:1000.jpg new name:1000-12x12.jpg
old name:1000.jpg new name:1000-15x15.jpg
```